# Authentication token for consumption from github api in nodejs

Tags: node.js, reactjs, github-api

```
const axios = require('axios');
require('dotenv').config();

const apiUsers = async (req, res) => {
  let { since } = req.query

    const { data, headers } = await axios.get(`https://api.github.com/users?since=${since}`, 
       headers: {
        'Authorization': 'token' + process.env.AUTH_TOKEN
      }
    });
```

**Result** = [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3dsfS.png)

if the token is passed correctly, the request limit should be 5000

**My .env archive below:**
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UDCeF.png)

Comment: please remove your images and replace them with text in the question. Your question also does not include a clear question? What is the problem?

Comment: You does not even provided a question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved
In this case the answer is 'Authorization': 'token ' + process.env.AUTH_TOKEN
The problem is the empty space after token... i forgot, but now is right!